# Angular DateRangePicker - make "To" and "From" fields readonly in Calender popup

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using Angular daterangepicker.I use the theme which shows 'To' and 'From' fields and 'Apply' and 'Close' buttons on left side when the calender pops up.

**calender:**

[image]

I need to make the highlighted fields readonly so that the user is forced to select the dates only from calender and click 'Apply'. The fields being editable allows to accept past dates. This is the behaviour i need to restrict

Comment: I'm assuming you are referring to this: https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker/ ?  have you considered just using the `min` and `max` properties that are offered by the directive?  If those aren't sufficient, then this would likely require you modifying the directive, or requesting the change to the project maintainers... this seems a bit much to ask here.

Comment: @Claies : Yup Exactly i am referring to the same daterangepicker link you provided. I do have min set ,which disables the past date.That's perfectly fine. My concern is once i select the dates from Calender and before clicking 'Apply' button, i get a chance to manipulate the dates using the 'To' and 'From' input fields that are just above 'Apply' button.This way if I provide a past date, the daterangepicker accepts that date and this is where my validation fails.Please refer the attached screenshot for more clearity on my problem

Comment: hmm, that sounds like a bug in the implementation to me;  again, seems an issue to take up with the project maintainers, unless you are asking *how* to modify the project, but the question is a bit too broad even to answer that....

Answer (score 0):

You can use datepicker-options and set the min date in options, this way your calender will not allow the user to select past dates.

```
<input type="text" datepicker-options="dateOptions" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" />
```

after this you need to set the options this way

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
minDate: new Date() 
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I do have 'min' property set. but I am able to manipulate the selected date range from 'To' and 'From' input fields which is just above 'Apply' button  and if i provide Past dates in those input fields, and clicking 'Apply' button accepts the past dates . I need to block these inputs coming from 'To' and 'from' fields ,so that only the dates from calender are considered.Please refer to the screenshot i have attached for more clearity.

Comment: http://dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/195/Disable-past-days-in-Angular-UI-bootstrap-datepicker.aspx

have a look here,

Answer (score 0):

I made the 'To' and 'From' fields readonly by using the showCalender.daterangepicker event. So, once the calender is shown, i added the readonly and disabled properties to the 'To' and 'From' input fields.This way, they are now not editable.

example:-

```
$scope.options = {
                  eventHandlers: {
                        'showCalendar.daterangepicker':function(ev,picker)
                        {
                            angular.element("input[name='daterangepicker_end']").prop("readonly",true)
                            angular.element("input[name='daterangepicker_end']").prop("disabled",true)
                            angular.element("input[name='daterangepicker_start']").prop("readonly",true)
                            angular.element("input[name='daterangepicker_start']").prop("disabled",true)
                        }
                    },
                };
```